# Simple Raw Packet Sniffer In Python

Tags: python, packet-sniffers, sniffing

First, I'm a beginner in python. I developed a simple raw packet sniffer utilizing the `PF_PACKET` interface that operates at layer 2.

The sniffer simply figures out the following...
- Ethernet Header (Source - Destination - Protocol)
- IP Header (Source IP - Destination IP)
- TCP Header(Source Port - Destination Port)

Here's the code I've written so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct
import socket
import binascii

rawSocket=socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.htons(0x0800))
#ifconfig eth0 promisc up
receivedPacket=rawSocket.recv(2048)

#Ethernet Header...
ethernetHeader=receivedPacket[0][0:14]
ethrheader=struct.unpack("!6s6s2s",ethernetHeader)
destinationIP= binascii.hexlify(ethrheader[0])
sourceIP= binascii.hexlify(ethrheader[1])
protocol= binascii.hexlify(ethrheader[2])
print "Destinatiom: " + destinationIP
print "Souce: " + sourceIP
print "Protocol: "+ protocol

#IP Header... 
ipHeader=receivedPacket[0][14:34]
ipHdr=struct.unpack("!12s4s4s",ipHeader)
destinationIP=socket.inet_ntoa(ipHdr[2])
print "Source IP: " +sourceIP
print "Destination IP: "+destinationIP

#TCP Header...
tcpHeader=receivedPacket[0][34:54]
tcpHdr=struct.unpack("!2s2s16s",tcpHeader)
sourcePort=socket.inet_ntoa(tcpHdr[0])
destinationPort=socket.inet_ntoa(tcpHdr[1])
print "Source Port: " + sourcePort
print "Destination Port: " + destinationPort
```

I seem to encounter a problem in the ethernet header part and the unpack method that I can't figure out. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the problem? If you are getting an exception, please paste the full exception output. If you are getting invalid results, please post the actual and expected output.

Comment: @PeterGibson struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 14. its in the ethernet part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `[0]` in your string slicing statement:

```
ethernetHeader=receivedPacket[0][0:14]
```

Should be just

```
ethernetHeader=receivedPacket[0:14]
```

The error is telling you that `struct.unpack` requires a string of length 14. If you print the string you're passing to it, you'll probably see that it only has length = 1. Here's an example:

```
>>> s = 'this is a test'
>>> s[0]
't'
>>> s[0][0:4]
't'
>>> s[0:4]
'this'
```

Comment: Yeah sir you are right. But isn't the received pack a tuple? That I need to unpack the first section in order to retrieve this info

Comment: No, socket.recv returns a string (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv).

Comment: You might have been thinking of `socket.recvfrom` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) which returns a tuple `(string, address)`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct
import sys,os
import socket
import binascii

rawSocket=socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.htons(0x0800))
#ifconfig eth0 promisc up
receivedPacket=rawSocket.recv(2048)

#Ethernet Header...
ethernetHeader=receivedPacket[0:14]
ethrheader=struct.unpack("!6s6s2s",ethernetHeader)
destinationIP= binascii.hexlify(ethrheader[0])
sourceIP= binascii.hexlify(ethrheader[1])
protocol= binascii.hexlify(ethrheader[2])

print "Destination: " + destinationIP
print "Source: " + sourceIP
print "Protocol: "+ protocol

#IP Header... 
ipHeader=receivedPacket[14:34]
ipHdr=struct.unpack("!12s4s4s",ipHeader)
destinationIP=socket.inet_ntoa(ipHdr[2])
sourceIP=socket.inet_ntoa(ipHdr[1])
print "Source IP: " +sourceIP
print "Destination IP: "+destinationIP

#TCP Header...
tcpHeader=receivedPacket[34:54]
tcpHdr=struct.unpack("!2s2s16s",tcpHeader)
sourcePort=socket.inet_ntoa(tcpHdr[0])
destinationPort=socket.inet_ntoa(tcpHdr[1])
print "Source Port: " + sourcePort
print "Destination Port: " + destinationPort
```