# Python socket sniffer not working on AIX5.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, aix

I'm trying to create a python network sniffing script that will grab certain traffic that I need to log.
So far I have not been able to sniff anything but ICMP packets which is strange since the same code works fine on linux.
Python version is 2.7.5

python code :

```
import socket
#create an INET, STREAMing socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind(('', 0))
# receive a packet
while True:
        print "Sniffing"
        packet = s.recvfrom(65565)
        print packet
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:

I tried changin the line where I create the socket to:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
```

That gave me no results. When I changed the line to this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
```

I got results that look a lot like that I got using the code above.

Then I tried this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x800))
```

But then I got an error message saying "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PF_PACKET'"

I also tried extracting the protocol using [this tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/) and got that all the packages were using protocol 1 (ICMP). I ran all of the above solutions on both Red Hat and Ubuntu systems without any problems.

I'm trying to keep the dependencies at minimum so I prefer to use socket rather than a third party library :-)

Comment: Your code worked fine on Windows 7. How can you be sure that it is sniffing only `ICMP` packets. There are already posts on SO regarding creating a network sniffer. eg: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24666039/2382792 I would recommend to try Scapy. http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I work only in a Linux/AIX environment so testing the sniffer in Windows won't get me far :-/ I edited my question above to answer you questions.

Comment: This error `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PF_PACKET'"` occured on your linux system?

Comment: No, not on the Linux system, just the AIX system.